# What causes the recursive cause in an exception?

Tags: java, exception

When looking at an exception in Java in a debugger you will often see that the cause is recursive to itself infinitely (I assume it's infinite).

e.g:

```
Exception1, 
  Caused by -> Exception2 
     Caused by -> Exception2
        Caused by -> Exception2
```

Why is this?

**NB: This is when looking at the code in a debugger, Eclipse in this case.**

Comment: I've never seen that... and I think without details it's hard to tell

Comment: Do you have any code you're referring to? It's much clearer if you have code + stack trace of the error

Comment: more details please, maybe a code?

Comment: I wondered if this would result in peeps asking for code.  I'll get some for you.  I've seen it happen in various places in the code.  More details shall be provided though...

Answer (score 20):

Looking at the [source code of Throwable](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Throwable.java.html):

```
  187       /**
  188        * The throwable that caused this throwable to get thrown, or null if this
  189        * throwable was not caused by another throwable, or if the causative
  190        * throwable is unknown.  If this field is equal to this throwable itself,
  191        * it indicates that the cause of this throwable has not yet been
  192        * initialized.
  193        *
  194        * @serial
  195        * @since 1.4
  196        */
  197       private Throwable cause = this;
```

So I guess what you are seeing is an Exception which was created without using one of the constructors which takes a cause.

You will see this in a debugger, but [getCause](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29) takes care of not returning the recursive reference:

```
  414       public synchronized Throwable getCause() {
  415           return (cause==this ? null : cause);
  416       }
```

Comment: Seems like a bug waiting to happen, if anyon ever invents time travel. What if an exception goes back in time and causes itself to happen? _Dun dun dunnnnn!_

Comment: I find this an interesting question. I frequently see exceptions thrown by underlying libraries that refernece themselves as their cause, thus creating an endless cycle. Why would one want to do this ??

Comment: This is interesting example of how hidden and encapsulated parts of an API can cause problems for developers (here someone tried to pack 2 values into one field, maybe for some performace reasons). I often find myself expanding `cause`es in IntelliJ and after ten levels wondering WTF...

Comment: I am pretty sure the IDE folks are aware of this problem, and they have probably been tempted to add some code to the debugger of the IDE to somehow cover it up, but they probably decided "it is not our fault -- the guys who built java should not be doing things in such a retarded way".